# Модификация Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, html5, cms, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста как в **Contact Form 7**, после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить", изменить **ajax-loader** на свой?

Раньше делал отправку формы не через плагин, а просто свой php обработчик, то там было несколько проще в этом плане.

Стандартно он находится возле кнопки отправки, как `span`с `background-image`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше я вообще писал для него целый `HTML` блок, так как делал на `CSS`:

```
<!--Loader-->
<div id="loader">
    <div id="circularG">
        <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG"></div>
        <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как можно также полностью убрать стандартное сообщение об успешной отправке, и подключить свое собственное окно благодарности? Спасибо

Comment: Картинку что ли? И ещё: одна задача/проблема: один вопрос(топик)

Comment: ajax-loader заменить - вообще не вопрос. Замените на свой код css, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вывести своё окно благодарности, надо использовать событие `wpcf7mailsent`. Вот примерный код на JQuery

```
$('.popup-form').on('wpcf7mailsent', function () {
    var sentPopup = $("#sent_popup");
    if (sentPopup.length) {
        // $.fancybox.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.fancybox(sentPopup.closest('.fancybox-hidden').html()); // Показать окно благодарности
            // Клик на кнопке "Ожидаю ответа" закрывает попап
            $('#fancybox-content .waiting-btn').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.fancybox.close();
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Здесь использован плагин [Easy FancyBox](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/). Разметка html под окно благодарности:

```
<div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">
    <div id="sent_popup" class="popup-form">Здесь ваша форма</div>
</div>
```

В форме кнопка с классом `.waiting-btn`, по клику на которую закрывается это всплывающее окно.

Таймаут в коде JQuery нужен был, потому что саму contact form 7 я выводил во всплывающем окне, по событию `wpcf7mailsent` закрывал его (закомментированная строка), и надо было подождать, пока fancybox "очухается". Без таймаута после закрытия окна открыть новое не получалось. Вы можете все это выкинуть. Оставил для примера, вдруг захотите и саму contact form 7 выводить во всплывающем окне.